# javascript - display html on node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

i'm new in nodejs. i'm trying to show html form via nodejs,here is my code :

```js
function start(response){
 console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
 var body = '<html>\n'+
 '<head>\n'+
 '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content = "text/html:'+
 'charset = UTF-8" />'+
 '</head>'+
 '<body>'+
 '<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
 '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
 '<input type="submit" value="submit text" />'+
 '</form>'+
 '</body>'+
 '</html>';
 response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
 response.write(body);
 response.end();
}
```

the problem is when i run the code server just give me html source check image :

[image]

where is my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
> ```

You've told the browser that you are sending it plain text, so it is rendering the document as plain text.

If you are sending HTML, then say it is HTML.

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `Content-Type` you've given.

```
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
```

It's `text/plain` which means browser will render the response as `PLAIN TEXT` instead of HTML.

What you need to do is set Valid content type to render the response as `HTML`.

For HTML correct Content Type is `text/html`. So your code would look something like this,

```
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
```

[List of content types](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)